# TSMP77000 IR Sensor Module for Remote Control Systems

Tags: embedded, pwm, infrared

I use tsmp77000 IR sensor module for remote control systems with tv remote controller. Tsmp77000 has active low output.

[from output of tsmp77000 with tv remote controller on/off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7bFq.png)

[from my mcu pwm output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GU29T.png)

I generated signal with 38kHz and %50 duty cycle. Time of this signal is same with tsmp77000 output. Description:

-1sn delay for next on/off action

-8.98ms 38kHz pwm signal

-1.96ms pwm output disable

-412us 38kHz pwm signal

```
TIM1_CtrlPWMOutputs(DISABLE);
for(int e=87;e>0;e--){ //1sn delay
delay_ms(16072); //5.8ms on/off delay
}

TIM1_CtrlPWMOutputs(ENABLE);
delay_ms(24020); //8.98ms 38kHz

TIM1_CtrlPWMOutputs(DISABLE);
delay_ms(5200); //1.96ms off

TIM1_CtrlPWMOutputs(ENABLE);
delay_ms(1105); //412us 38kHz
```

But, it does not on/off. What am I doing wrong? Thank You!

Comment: What is a "1sn" delay?  What units are "sn"?  Seconds are indicated by just "s".  5.8ms x 87 is about 0.5 of a second, however would expect a function with a name `delay_ms` to take an argument in milliseconds, meaning the initial loop would take  1.6 x 87 seconds (139 seconds)

Comment: It would probably be simpler and more accurate increment a counter in the TIM1 reload interrupt, and enable/disable the PWM output when the counter reaches the required number of pulses (where 380000 = 1 second), resetting the counter at the same time for the next period.  You can then generate any complex waveform simply by reading from a sequence of timing values.